# WPF Style Triggers TemplateBinding

Tags: wpf, controltemplates

I'm new to WPF and I am struggling to find the solution to what I'm trying to do as I'm still a little uncertain as to whether I'm doing this correctly.

I have the following style defined for a button

```
<Style x:Key="ToolBarButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CompanyBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">               
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" BorderThickness="5" CornerRadius="5"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}">
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>


            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Button.Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,-0.2" EndPoint="0,1.2">
                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="{ORIGINAL-COLOR}" Offset="0.5" />
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

In the XAML, where I have put the placeholder `{ORIGINAL-COLOR}`, I essentially want this to be the value that is used previously set with `{TemplateBinding Background}` for the control template of the style.

I've seen suggestions that I should use `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background}` but this is not working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: In what way is it not working? What's the message/error or does it fail silently. Make sure you check the output window, because that's where WPF dumps a lot of debug information.

Comment: You can't bind `Color` with `Background` property since return type of  `Background` is `Brush` and not `Color`.

Comment: The error I get is as follows: Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Background.Color; DataItem=null; target element is 'GradientStop' (HashCode=19346574); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')

Comment: is ORIGINAL-COLOR static or dynamic?

Comment: ORIGINAL-COLOR is a placeholder for whatever should be there. That error I was from using {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background.Color}

Comment: I just have copied and pasted the above code . Its Trigger is not working at all.

Comment: If I replace {ORIGINAL-COLOR} with a hardcoded value such as 'White' then it would work as expected, but I'm trying to have it be the same color as the original background, rather then hard-coding the value.

Comment: yes thats what i was asking that is original background static or dynamic . if it is static then you can just replace it harcoded like White

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `LinearGradientBrush` is not a `FrameworkElement` and doesn't belong to layout tree. Only `FrameworkElements` have `DataContext` property and in consequence can make use of bindings. What you're trying to do is to set up a `Binding` on `GradientStop`.

Your trigger should look like this:

```
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Button.Background" 
                        Value="{TemplateBinding Background, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}">
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
```

And `myConverter` is a custom converter class that will take value of Background and return a complete `LinearGradientBrush` instance created from input brush. I'll assume you know how to write converters. Remember it needs to be added to resources.

More or less something like this:

```
    class BrushToGradient : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var brush = (Brush)value;
        var gradient = new LinearGradientBrush();

        //Make it manually
        gradient.GradientStops.Add(...);
        //...
        return gradient;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this solution to work with a couple of tweaks. In the trigger, the TemplateBinding shortcut cannot be used, and also, because of my actual control template I also needed to set the TargetName attribute on the Setter: `<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ButtonBorder" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ToolBarSolidToLinearGradient}}" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind `Color` with `Background` property since return type of `Background` is `Brush` and not `Color`.

Bind with Color property of `Brush`. Since background is binded to resource `CompanyBlue` so use that binding in your trigger as well -

```
<GradientStop Color="{Binding Color, Source={StaticResource CompanyBlue}}"
              Offset="0.5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0" />
<GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource CompanyBlue}"  Offset="0.5" />
<GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1" />
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: That would help if I wanted it to always be that value, but it can be overwritten when using the style (which is why I set the background to `{TemplateBinding Background}`) and would want that overwritten value to be used in this scenario.